# How to retrieve the current page name in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Is there a way in JSP to know the current page name (not the entire URL or URI)? Of course, we can do something like the following to retrieve the current page name in JSP.

```
String servletPath=request.getServletPath();
out.println(servletPath.substring(servletPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1, servletPath.length()));
```

This can retrieve the current page name (may be I'm following the wrong way to do so). Is there a fair and direct way in JSP to retrieve the current page name?

[Also, the separator character `/` in this method `servletPath.lastIndexOf("/")` should always be independent of any file system supported by any Operating System].

Comment: I'm leery of wanting to know this.

Comment: You already have found one of the ways. What exactly is your problem? The separator character? This is nonsense. You're probably confusing URLs with local disk file system paths. They're not the same. The path separator in URLs is always `/`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it with URI method also.

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();

String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```